# Reading a file in python via read()

Tags: python

Consider this snippet

```
from sys import argv    
script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

current_file = open(input_file)          
print_all(current_file)
```

**Ref. line 4:** Why do I have to use "print" along with "f.read()". When I use just f.read() it doesnt print anything, why ?

Comment: Why do you expect just `f.read()` inside a function to print anything? Unless you *return* anything from a function, *or* explicitly print in a function, a function's effects are not going to be automatically visible, even in the python interactive interpreter.

Comment: In most cases, the job of a function or method follows its name: `read()` reads (and nothing else), `seek()` moves the file pointer etc. So it is clear what `read()` does - it reads. If you intend to process the data just read, put it into a variable and process it. If you want to print it, do that: `print f.read()`.

Answer (score 2):

`f.read()` reads the file from disk into memory. `print` prints to the console. You will find more info on input and output in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)